# what so special about a use of goto in a chain of if else

Tags: c++, optimization

I was watching a video of Alexandrescu's, he has the following code snippet:

```
 // an example implementation of a single threaded shared_ptr
 ~SingleThreadPtr() { 
    if(!c_) {
       soSueMe: delete p_;
    } else if(--*c_ == 0) {
       delete c_;
       goto soSueMe;
    }
 }
```

This is here https://youtu.be/Qq_WaiwzOtI?t=36m44s. He says, "I use my famous 'goto soSueMe' construct", and says "try to write this without goto and [..] you'll see it is difficult".

What is so difficult here? Isn't the following the same, and *obviously* not difficult, and more readible:

```
 // an example implementation of a single threaded shared_ptr
 ~SingleThreadPtr() { 
    if(!c_) {
       delete p_;
    } else if(--*c_ == 0) {
       delete c_;
       delete p_;
    }
 }
```

or is that not even the same (thereby reinforcing the arguments against `goto` in the first place)? What sort of hacker's black magic voodoo going on here?

Comment: Probably he was talking about rewriting the code without the usage of goto, and avoiding code duplication. It's easy when the common part between cases is a single line, but imagine that line representing 50 lines of code, will you, really, copy-paste that, like you did with a single line?

Comment: No, make it a function...

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So you'd encapsulate it into a private function.

Comment: @Xirema Yes, I get that, and I would do so myself, but I was trying to get into the mind of the person who raised this question.

Comment: Is a `std::shared_ptr` an option? It would take care of the memory management, leaving the destructor empty.

Comment: @MarianSpanik This is an implementation of a shared pointer. It would be redundant to use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @MarianSpanik The author of the code is explicitly writing a sample implementation of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: For lack of a better way of putting it, the guy in that video is full of cr*p.

Comment: (See NickLamp's answer below. It's identical to the YouTube video's logic, more readable, and more maintainable.)

Comment: @JimBuck the answer you're pointing to is not correct (unless there's something I'm missing). It deletes the object regardless of the reference count.

Comment: @JimBuck seems like you have no idea who "that guy in the video" is, otherwise you would not write such "cr*p" about him :P

Comment: @Steve: Alexandrescu is talking about "highly optimized" code. You won't do a function call within an implementation of a sharedptr class if you can avoid it.

Comment: Or why not `if (c_) { if (--*c_ != 0) return; delete c_; } delete p_;`

Comment: Yup, I don't know who that guy is, but his statement taken at face value is false, even when factoring in optimizations/inlining/etc.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Seems equivalent ... is it potentially because he wants to put the most common branch (where `c_` is null) first?

Comment: @cwschmidt Granted :)  However, that was in response to `imagine that line representing 50 lines of code`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The point here is that shared_ptr destructors are called relatively often, and generally inline, and this is an attempt to reduce the inlined destructor size (as a `goto` is much smaller than a delete call).

For example, the destructor call `delete p_` when compiled may look something like:

```
LBB5_8:
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax         ## 8-byte Reload
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    cmpq    $0, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -24(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    je  LBB5_4
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax         ## 8-byte Reload
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   __ZdlPv                 
LBB5_4:
```

(where the `callq   __ZdlPv` is the underlying object destructor finally being called).

Whereas the `goto` looks simply like this:

```
LBB5_8:
    jmp LBB5_2
```

Thus, by branching rather than repeating the `delete p_` statement, codesize is significantly reduced.

[This accompanying presentation](http://emma.memect.com/t/a3aaa8af0141504cef885600f386090e25ad9df3e116f3d5e0875071784b7b95/Optimization%20Tips%20-%20Andrei%20Alexandrescu%20-%20CppCon%202014.pdf) may prove useful reading (although terse).

Comment: i guess he explains it in the video and I am pretty sure this piece of code is well thought-out, he even calls it the "go-to solution for reference counting" (slide 12)

Comment: It just sounds like this is just poor optimization on the part of the compiler.

Comment: Why is using the `goto` also better than `~SingleThreadPtr() { if(c_ && --*c_ == 0) delete c_; delete p_; }`?

Comment: @bcmpinc Assuming you mean ~SingleThreadPtr() { if(c_ && --*c_ == 0) {delete c_; delete p_; }} then its because you also have to `delete p_` when `!c_`  (the counter is lazily created, if there is only one instance, c_ may be null, see the presentation)

Comment: @donkopotamus: The lack of braces is intentional, such that `delete p_;` is executed regardless of the if-branch.

Comment: @bcmpinc Then you just deleted the object if there was a counter and its > 0

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the following code is simpler to understand? The compiler produced even less assembly instructions as well:

```
~SingleThreadPtr() { 
    if (c_) {
       if (--*c_ != 0) {
            return;
       }
       delete c_;
    }
    delete p_;
}
```

Assembly instructions:

```
test        rcx,rcx  
je          wmain+0C8h (013F3813D8h)  
dec         dword ptr [rcx]  
jne         wmain+0D5h (013F3813E5h)  
call        qword ptr [__imp_operator delete (013F3831E8h)]  
mov         rcx,qword ptr [p_ (013F385708h)]  
call        qword ptr [__imp_operator delete (013F3831E8h)]
```

The original code below:

```
~SingleThreadPtr() { 
    if(!c_) {
       soSueMe: delete p_;
    } else if(--*c_ == 0) {
       delete c_;
       goto soSueMe;
    }
 }
```

Generates the following assembly code:

```
test        rcx,rcx  
je          wmain+0A5h (013F3813B5h)  
dec         dword ptr [rcx]  
jne         wmain+0B9h (013F3813C9h)  
call        qword ptr [__imp_operator delete (013F3831E8h)]  
mov         rcx,qword ptr [p_ (013F385708h)]  
call        qword ptr [__imp_operator delete (013F3831E8h)]  
mov         rcx,qword ptr [c_ (013F385710h)]
```

Comment: Your solution will  *always* run `delete p_;` in the destructor which is not what you want all the time. If `*c_` already hold greater than `1` then only the countdown is wanted, i.e., `--*c_`.

Comment: You are wrong, the following code will make it return in cases where p should not be deleted. Read the code first please.

`if (c_) {
       if (--*c_ != 0) {
            return;`
.....

Comparing this to the original code, it preserves the same effects. 

`if(!c_) {
       soSueMe: delete p_;
    } else if(--*c_ == 0) {
       delete c_;
       goto soSueMe;
    }
`